# Exhaustive switches

Tags: c#, swift, switch-statement

I recently started learning Swift and came across a Swift switches, it seems that switches must be exhaustive in Swift, for example.

This will cause a compiler error

```
let nums = 1...5
for num in nums 
{
    switch num
    {
       case 2:
           // Do Something
       // Will throw a comilation error unless default: was added
    }
}
```

Whilst in C#, this is perfectly acceptable

```
var nums = new[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
foreach (var num in nums)
{
    switch (num)
    {
        case 2:
            // Do Something
            break;
    }
}
```

Is this just a infrastructure preference or is there some other reason for this?

Comment: Are you asking why do you need to add default in swift or why you don't in c#?

Comment: Yes, seemed weird to me why C# allows this and Swift doesn't when switch seems to be a very basic keyword in every language

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Swift has *chosen* to a few things differently than other languages, otherwise there would not be a need for a new language.

This is especially true for `switch` which has e.g. chosen to not `fallthrough` unless being told so explicitly. This allows it to omit the pervasive `break` from other C-like languages (which I consider an excellent choice btw. considering that I very rarely want my `case` to fall through).

It is also not unheard of to have languages require `default` for `switches`, e.g. for `Java` when switching on `enum`s as in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5013194/why-is-default-required-for-a-switch-on-an-enum-in-this-code). In this case I would generally consider this a *good thing*, as I might otherwise forget to add a case in some random `switch` statement where I intended to cover all the values of an `enum` or range if the `enum` eventually gets an additional element. This way I have a way to express this (by not implementing a `default` clause) which I consider superior to not having this possibility (by simply assuming "nothing to be done" as in the case of C#).

Comment: Just for completeness, C# does not allow "fallthrough" either.  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3047863/how-can-i-use-more-than-one-constant-for-a-switch-case-in-c/3049601#3049601

Comment: Thanks for this clarification. I do not know C# well enough to be able to make this distinction, but it is absolutely something to be pointed out.

Comment: I guess my question should have been why did Swift choose to not fallthrough or allow breaks