# In C++, if break; keyword not exist for Switch case block, both case "b" & default is executed

Tags: c++

```
bool condition = true;
string input = "b";

switch (input)
{
    case "b":
        if (condition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default");
        break;
}
```

C++:

```
B
Default
```

Comment: Those two are different languages.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Switch statement fallthrough in C#?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/174155/switch-statement-fallthrough-in-c)

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does C# have break if it's not optional?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3108888/why-does-c-sharp-have-break-if-its-not-optional)

Comment: C# does not allow switch case statements to flow into another case statement...its a very common C++ bug...so C# tries to protect you from it. Therefore you MUST have a `break;` in each `case`.

Comment: you must have to put a break after each case.

Comment: Hm.. If `input` is `a`, why would it go in `b` case of your switch?

Comment: You can't use strings for switches in C++ in the first place.

Comment: And the answer is pretty simple. C++ and C# are not the same language, they implement different specs. Why would you even think about comparing their behavior?

Comment: I would write something like 

switch (input)
{
    case "b":
    default:
        if (input == "b" && condition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
        Console.WriteLine("Default");
        break;
}

Answer (score 3):

you missed a break after case,

```
bool condition = true;
string input = "a";
switch (input)
{
    case "b":
        if (condition)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("B");
        }
        break; // You missed break;
    default:
        Console.WriteLine("Default");
        break;
}
```

C# does not allow to execute more than one case which is logically incorrect so prevented by C# compiler.

Comment: Note that you can do `goto default` or `goto case "c"` instead of `break`ing as well.

Comment: I don't know about ‘*logically incorrect*’, it can be quite useful in some cases (no pun intended).

Comment: jump statements (goto) would not give you any compilation error but might increase the complexity of your code, hence are not a good programming habit to use.

Comment: @Biffen: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6545720/does-anyone-still-use-goto-in-c-sharp-and-if-so-why

Comment: @JitendraPancholi I wasn't talking about goto, I was talking about case fallthrough.

Comment: @Biffen: Oops I tagged you by mistake, I should tag to YoryeNathan.